# How to get list of all users that have created the posts

Tags: eloquent

I have two tables in my database.

```
    Users
         id,name
    Posts
         id,user_id,name 

    // user_id is the id who has created the post.

    How do i get list of all users that have created the posts.

    Relation in users table is like this.
    => user HasMany posts.

    The relation in Post Class 
    => post belongsTo users.


    What i have tried so far

    $uses = User::with('posts')->get();
    This returns list of all users,that has not even created the post
```

Do i need to update or create new relation for this?

Comment: why you are down voting it,is information is not clear? or the question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to dig into Laravel Eloquent.Have a look into this [URL](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships)

By the way you can try this.

```
$users = User::has('posts')->get();
```

It will return list of all users with posts.